# Как скачать файл из публичной папки Яндекс.Диск

Tags: vue.js, firebase, yandex-disk

Есть приложение с фронтом на Vue и с бэком на Firebase и есть публичная папка на Яндекс Диске, с задачей вывода папок и файлов справился с помощью REST API. Но со скачиванием файлов есть проблемы.

Делаю запрос на `https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources` получаю папки и файлы, у файлов есть поле `file` со ссылкой на скачивание, но при попытке скачать получаю 403.

Answer (score 0):

тебе не даст это сделать политика конфиденциальности Яндекса скорее всего

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код выглядит так:

````
import requests

base_url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download?'
link = 'https://disk.yandex.ru/d/SvcMXspUAGSb6Q'  # Сюда вписываете вашу ссылку

# Получаем загрузочную ссылку
final_url = base_url + 'public_key=' + link
response = requests.get(final_url)
download_url = response.json()['href']

# Загружаем файл и сохраняем его
download_response = requests.get(download_url)
with open('downloaded_file.txt', 'wb') as f:   # Здесь укажите нужный путь к файлу
    f.write(download_response.content)```
````

Comment: Если ответ был полезным и рабочим можете отметить его галочкой либо треугольником:)

Comment: А еще лучше дайте код чтобы посмотреть что там у вас

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но в окружении нет python-а

Comment: Спасибо! Скрипт работает!